# How to remove red underline from PyCharm project window files?

Tags: python, pycharm

My PyCharm 2016.3 is underlining some files like it's spellchecking them. I suspect this can be controlled from the Settings/Editor/Inspections menu, but I can't find it. How can this be removed?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: They are not underlined for spellchecking but for errors in the code of the files, in your case there is an error in urls.py, that's why you get the red lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an error in `urls.py` that's triggering the error highlight for both of its parent folders (see "[Error Indication](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Syntax+highlighting+and+error+indication)"). Spellchecking warnings are usually displayed in green, and don't apply to filenames.

In any case, you can change the syntax highlighting and error indications in `Editor→Colors and Fonts→General`. Or, you can use "Hector The Code Inspector" (the little icon resembling a guy with a hat) to change the highlighting policy per-file.

Answer (score -1):

red line under text code in django .
This warning is because the curnet interpreter is not selected correctly.
Go to pycharm settings -> python interpreter -> select your project python version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33664146)

Answer (score -2):

Go to file->settings->editor and click on Inspections then you can see Spelling, uncheck the checkbox corresponding to that and click apply and OK. Hope this is useful.